# How to recover partition deleted in windows and then installed ubuntu 16.04 on hard drive

Tags: 16.04, windows-7, data-recovery, partitioning

I was running Microsoft Windows7 with 5 partitions naming as C(Windows Installation), D, E,F,G on 500GB hard drive. By some mistake I deleted partition D using Windows disk management tool. After that I installed Ubuntu 16.04. After installing Ubuntu I came know that I left with one partition of around ~500GB and I am not seeing any partition  present in windows OS. After some efforts I was able to recover partition E,F,G(C I don't care as it has Windows OS). But I am not able to recover D.
Is there any way to get recover D?

Edit:
Guys its not duplicate of any existing question. Please find uniqueness as below:

"I deleted one partition in windows then installed Ubuntu 16.04. Now in Ubuntu I am seeing only single partition. So I want to recover my that partition which was deleted in windows."

If still you see its exact duplicate then can you please provide link to original question.

Thank you

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and include the output of `sudo lsblk -f`, `sudo parted -l` and ideally a screenshot of the drive as seen by GParted? It would help if you also added a description where the missing partition was located if you happen to know that. Thanks. (In the mean time I'm voting to keep this question closed because we lack information to properly discern whether it's a duplicate.)